# Python: faster alternative to numpy's random.choice()?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to sample 1000 numbers between 0 and 999, with a vector of weights dictating the probability that a particular number will be chosen:

```
import numpy as np
resampled_indices = np.random.choice(a = 1000, size = 1000, replace = True, p = weights)
```

Unfortunately, this process has to be run thousands of times in a larger for loop, and it seems that `np.random.choice` is the main speed bottleneck in the process. As such, I was wondering if there's any way to speed up `np.random.choice` or to use an alternative method that gives the same results.

Comment: Are the weights going to be the same for each call?  If so, it might be worth the time to pre-generate a big array by replicating each value according to its weight, and do a simple unweighted `random.choice()` on that array each time.

Comment: `np.random.choice` is `built-in` - i.e. compiled already.  Play around with generating larger samples, e.g. (1000,1000).  I don't know whether the `weights` make much of a difference or not.  That could depend on how they are implemented.

Comment: @jasonharper, unfortunately the weights change after each iteration.

Comment: try `numpy.random.multinomial` or `scipy.stats.multinomial` though I doubt it will be faster

Comment: `numpy.random.multinomial` used to be a lot faster (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7543), but I think it is fixed now

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can do slightly faster by using a uniform sampling and then "inverting" the cumulative distrubtion using `np.searchsorted`:

```
# assume arbitrary probabilities
weights = np.random.randn(1000)**2
weights /= weights.sum()

def weighted_random(w, n):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(w)
    rdm_unif = np.random.rand(n)
    return np.searchsorted(cumsum, rdm_unif)

# first method
%timeit np.random.choice(a = 1000, size = 1000, replace = True, p = weights)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 220 µs per loop

# proposed method
%timeit weighted_random(weights, n)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop
```

Now we can check empirically that the probabilities are correct:

```py
samples =np.empty((10000,1000),dtype=int)
for i in xrange(10000):
    samples[i,:] = weighted_random(weights)

empirical = 1. * np.bincount(samples.flatten()) / samples.size
((empirical - weights)**2).max()
# 3.5e-09
```

Answer (score 0):

For smaller sample sizes I find that the python 3.6 function, `random.choices`, is faster. In the script below, the break-even is at a sample size of 99, and `random.choices` becomes increasingly faster than 'numpy.random.choice' as the sample size decreases. With no weights, the break-even number is slightly higher at 120. However, for a population size of 1000, `random.choices` is about 3 times slower with weights, and 7 times slower without weights.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

SIZE = 98


def numpy_choice():
    for count in range(10000):
        resampled_indices = np.random.choice(a=population_array, size=SIZE, replace=True, p=weights)
    return


def python_choices():
    for count in range(10000):
        resampled_indices = random.choices(population_list,  weights=weights, k=SIZE)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    weights = [1/SIZE for i in range(SIZE)]
    population_array = np.arange(SIZE)
    population_list = list(population_array)

    start_time = time.time()
    numpy_choice()
    end_time = time.time()
    print('numpy.choice time:', end_time-start_time) 
    # gave 0.299

    start_time = time.time()
    python_choices()
    end_time = time.time()
    print('python random.choices time:', end_time-start_time)
    # gave 0.296
```